# How can I enclose a component with another container at runtime?

Tags: java, swing

What I'm trying to achive is basically the "Enclose in" feature of Netbeans at runtime:

Let's say I have this component hierarchy:

```
Container
    Label 1
    Label 2
    Label 3
```

And I want to enclose `Label 2` like this:

```
Container
    Label 1
    Container
        Label 2
    Label 3
```

And I also want to revert it, i.e. I want to "pull up" the label again to get the original hierarchy.

**EDIT:** The problem is that at runtime I only know `Label 2`. Any other components (siblings, parents, children) are unknown. That eliminates the possibitlity to just reconstruct the hierarchy.

Of couse I'm sure I can find *some* way to get this functionality by traversing the component hierarchies, but I wonder:

Is there a better way? Perhaps some kind of utility class which provides this encapsulation feature?

**EDIT 2:** How do I get the layout constraints the component originally was added to the container? I need this information because the new container has to use the same constraints. Also when restoring the original hierarchy the component has to re-use its old constraints.

Answer (score 1):

`Container`s are `Component`s as well, so it is possible to enclose `Container`s in `Container`s.

So, perhaps the first state would be something along the line of (pseudocode):

```
Container container1 = new Container();
Label label1 = new Label();
Label label2 = new Label();
Label label3 = new Label();
container1.add(label1);
container1.add(label2);
container1.add(label3);
```

To transition to the second state:

```
Container container2 = new Container();
container1.remove(label2);
container2.add(label2);
container2.add(container1);
```

Now, the `label2` is moved into `container2` and that container itself is contained in `container1`.

And to return to the original state:

```
container2.remove(label2);
container1.add(label1);
container1.remove(container2);
```

**Edit**

If all we know is `label2` itself, that is already contained in some `Container`, we can determine the parent `Container` by calling the `Component`'s [`getParent()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent()) method.

Applying that to the code above, replace the line for making `container1` with the following:

```
Container container1 = label2.getParent();
```

If you want to get the `Component`s which are held in the `Container`, the [`getComponents()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) method can be called in order to retrieve an array of `Component`s.

Comment: OK, that was way easier than I thought. For some reason I was convinced that I have to maintain the original order of the children to keep the layout but then I realized that the order has nothing to do with it... *doh*.

Comment: Visual ordering of the components are going to be the job of the LayoutManager, which is of course a big topic in itself!

Comment: Yeah, normally I'd know... Lack of sleep or caffeine... or both :)

Comment: How do I get the constraints the component was added to the container? Because the enclosing component has to get the same.